# Set function in Python 2.2

Tags: python

I have a problem regarding set in Python 2.2.
Currently I am just comparing between two lists like so:

```
temp3 = set(list1) - set(list2)
```

But it keeps prompting me that set isn't define. I used 2.7 to create the program. 
Updating software is not an option sadly.
Is there an alternative I can use?

Comment: unlucky, you missed out on `sets.Set` by one release

Comment: Is this your only use-case for sets? Comparison of arrays is pretty straight forward.

Comment: `sets` module got in python 2.3 and that is also replaced by `set` and `frozenset`. so.. better upgrade?

Comment: 2.2 is pretty old. Any reason you're using it?

Answer (score 1):

You can try third-party modules which provide the missing `set` functionality.  For example, [demset](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/demset).

The simplest way to use this module is to keep it in the same directory as the program you are writing and import the desired contents like so:

```
from demset import set
```

The [documentation](http://deron.meranda.us/python/demset/pydoc) as well as [home page](http://deron.meranda.us/python/demset/) mention a way to use Python's built-in `set` (and `frozenset`) when available, and only use the versions in the `demset` module when the built-ins are not available:

```
try:
    type(frozenset)
except NameError:
    from demset import set, frozenset
```

Aside from those imports, your program can stay exactly the same.

Note that I mentioned keeping the `demset` module in the same directory as your program only because this doesn't require any installation, and if you are stuck on Python 2.2, it sounds like maybe you are not allowed to install anything.

Comment: May I know how to use it? I am still new in Python(only a few weeks knowledge) Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're doing something massive you can probably just write your own function for this like the one below.

```
tmp3=[]
for i in list1:
  if i not in list2 and i not in tmp3:
    tmp3.append(i)
```